# How to restrict Google Cloud Storage bucket path to specific users without Firebase Storage rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage, acl

I am building a mobile app that requires my Cloud Storage bucket to be in Paris.
Therefore, i can't use Firebase Storage since this region is not available there.

I have setup a python backend using Cloud Functions to upload / delete files.

A file in my bucket looks like this : `https://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket/644f1576-9e2f-486e-b33f-e326b6c596e/folder1/6fiz576-9e2f-486e-b33f-e3b6c5996e/folder2/8b205722-c132-4ca2-b104-6f357f58a679.jpg`

The uid `644f1576-9e2f-486e-b33f-e326b6c596e` is like a group and i need to grant access to all the files below only for users that belongs to this group in my backend.
If that's not possible, i would like to at least prevent access from any unauthorized user (using Firebase Auth as login method).

With Firebase Storage Rules i guess it would be possible, but since i can't use them i don't really know how should i proceed here... I am not very confident of adding a service account file in my mobile app client code.

For now all my files are public and i need at least to restrict access to the (authenticated) users of my app.
And also for now, if i paste the URL in my browser it's readable and i can't allow that.

Thanks in advance

Edit : i have already went through the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/) which, while helpful, doesn't answer the common use cases.

It provides tools to setup permissions but no examples of "how to authenticate to a Cloud Storage bucket using Firebase auth" for example.

EDIT 2 :

Here is a sample of my python code in my cloud function :

```
@functions_framework.http
def users(event):
    method = event.method
    endpoint = event.path
    headers = event.headers
    route_key = method + " " + endpoint
    logging.info(f"Route key : {route_key}")
    user_auth_id = ""
    if "Authorization" in headers:
        user_auth_id = check_token(headers["Authorization"])
    if user_auth_id == "":
        return {"error": "not allowed"}
    if route_key == "POST /upload":
        file = event.files
        body = event.form
        return upload_file(user_auth_id, file, body)
    return {"error": "not allowed"}

def check_token(token):
    try:
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(token)
        logging.info(f"verified token : {decoded_token}")
        if "disabled" in decoded_token and decoded_token["disabled"]:
            return "disabled"
        if "uid" in decoded_token:
            return decoded_token["uid"]
        return ""
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"check_token : {e}")
        return ""

def upload_file(user_auth_id, files, payload):
    try:
        photo = files["url"] if "url" in files else ""
        logging.info(f"Payload upload : {payload}")
        uid = payload["uid"]
        if photo != "":
            name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".jpg"
            bucket_name = os.environ.get("BUCKET_NAME")
            bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
            delete_files(user_auth_id, profile_photo=True, bucket=bucket)
            blob = bucket.blob(f"documents/{uid}/users/" + user_auth_id + "/profile/" + name)
            logging.info(f"Blob : {blob.path}")
            blob.upload_from_string(photo.read())
            blob.make_public()
            return blob.public_url
        return ""
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"upload_file: {e}")
        return ""


def delete_files(user_auth_id, uid, profile_photo=False, bucket=None):
    try:
        if not bucket:
            bucket_name = os.environ.get("BUCKET_NAME")
            bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        path = "/profile" if profile_photo else ""
        blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=f'documents/{uid}/users/' + user_auth_id + path)
        for blob in blobs:
            blob.delete()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"delete_files: {e}")
        return {"error": "internal"}
```

The `upload_file` method returns the public URL that i store in my DB, then my clients can "read" this URL but i would like to restrict access to this URL if possible without using adding backend code (only using Cloud Storage rules somehow if possible ?)

Comment: can you have a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/)

Comment: I have already read it actually, i will link it in my question. 
This explains the concepts but i need some working procedure or steps to follow for my use case.

Comment: Folder does not exist and it's not a resource. You can't enforce IAM permission and policies on them. You have to do it yourselves, by code. Or create a bucket per UUID and grant the correct permission on each bucket

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere, but how does Firebase storage security rules work then ? I think there is only one bucket right ?

Comment: Firebase is a wrapper on top of Google Cloud. Special things are implemented in the wrapper, that are not native to Google Cloud. That's the trick!

Comment: You are right ! Would it be possible to know actually how are made the trick for this use case ? I don't think it would mentioned in the documentation as developers would usually go for Firebase Storage APIs directly (as i did in other projects i have)

Answer (score 1):

I understand that:

1. Your users are authenticated on your mobile app via the Firebase Authentication service. So the user has a [Firebase ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#auth_tokens), which is a  signed JWT that securely identifies the user in your Firebase project.
2. The user calls your Python base back-end with an image and the  back-end uploads it to your Paris located bucket

If the above assumptions are correct you could do as follows:

- When the app calls your Python back-end pass the Firebase ID token and then, in your back-end, verify this ID token using the Firebase Admin SDK, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk). You get the user's uid.
- Based on the user's uid check that this user belongs to the desired group (I don't know how you have set-up your group based access strategy, maybe via [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) or through [Firestore documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access)?) and grant (or not) access accordingly.

---

The mechanism is the same for deletion. When calling your Python base back-end you just pass the file URL instead of passing a file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! This is actually exactly what i have done for write and delete. 
Maybe it was not clear but my question is about the READ since i have the storage URL in my database stored but that is public. And i would like this URL to check for authentication before allowing the read. 

Should i not store the file URL then ? but rather another endpoint that would do the same as you told in python (decoding the JWT token to get the uid etc..) ?

Comment: I have edited the question with my current code so you see that i have implemented what you suggested which works very fine for write and delete, but not for reads... Even if i had a new endpoint for reads, how to "allow" the read on the URL if it's not public ?

Comment: I understand that you want to directly read the file from the bucket and not go through the Python backend to do so. One option is to 1/ Totally close access to the buckket, and 2/ Generate in the back-end a temporary signedURL that you pass back to the user. (I know it is an extra call to the back-end but I don't see any other possibility)

Comment: alright thanks for your help and confirmation then, i prefer to know that there is no other possibility rather than keep wondering if there are any

Comment: To be complete, note that I didn't say that there is no other possibility, just that I personally don't see any other possibility :-)

Comment: oh thanks for the clarification, i will let this question without answer for now if someone come up with another solution :) 
In the meantime, i will simply generate signed urls when i query the documents that are supposed to have URLs and remove the URLs from the database. I will get aside the URLs based on their ID.